# Slow down when trying to copy database to new database

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchdb-python

I am trying to transfer all the documents out of my large couchdb db, and appear to hit a serious slow down shortly after starting. The request being used to get the documents is:

```
url = 'http://<ip>:5984/marketwatch_weekly/_all_docs?include_docs=true&limit=4000&skip=%s' % skip
```

The print out of the slow down is below. The furthest right column is the time in seconds for the request to complete. The column next to that one is the skip amount.

```
getting 2018-03-22 20:53:31.523599 16833 364000  89.11844325065613
getting 2018-03-22 20:55:02.698881 17478 368000  89.88783812522888
getting 2018-03-22 20:56:33.738854 19864 372000  90.0836386680603
getting 2018-03-22 20:57:56.869204 21151 376000  82.24904656410217
getting 2018-03-22 20:59:09.616417 23135 380000  72.10899209976196
getting 2018-03-22 21:00:18.940941 24875 384000  68.40224647521973
getting 2018-03-22 21:01:41.423078 25589 388000  81.92294359207153
getting 2018-03-22 21:11:47.979055 6395 392000  605.9177582263947
getting 2018-03-22 21:31:37.420515 1425 396000  1188.589150428772
getting 2018-03-22 21:46:11.717596 0 400000  873.0646567344666
getting 2018-03-22 22:02:38.413917 0 404000  985.686975479126
getting 2018-03-22 22:20:19.832703 0 408000  1060.2585520744324
getting 2018-03-22 22:39:29.712637 0 412000  1148.8915960788727
getting 2018-03-22 22:59:27.880014 0 416000  1197.4601407051086
getting 2018-03-22 23:21:09.851654 0 420000  1300.9372861385345
getting 2018-03-22 23:45:07.953314 0 424000  1436.5531301498413
```

Wondering what might be causing this, and any tips to correct this? Should I set include_docs to false and request each doc my its _id instead?

I'm using my own data transfer script as I'm changing the schema of the database as well, so I can't really use any sort of replication tools.

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't provide your transfer script, maybe that's the cause of the issues you're facing?

Comment: `... changing the schema of the database as well, so I can't  ...`, there is no *schema* in CouchDB, am I right?

Comment: There is in the sense that there is a structure I want the data in. Previously it was all stock options data for a given time and stock all in one doc, now I'm breaking that doc into smaller docs which have just a single option on each doc

Comment: I set include_docs to false and that helped a fair bit for awhile, but still ran into slowdown. Now I'm trying couchdb compaction. Hopefully that reorgs the data nicely and makes smaller doc sizes in turn making faster reads.

Answer (score 0):

couchdb compaction seems to have done the trick

Answer (score 0):

One reason I also ran into this was using [`validate_doc_update`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/ddocs.html#validate-document-update-functions) in design documents. As soon as a design doc with a validate function is added to the target database, every document will be passed through this function, which considerably slows down replications.